# Placing the caption in adjacent row

Tags: floats, captions, two-column

In a two column document, I have 1 column long figure. Hence, the caption does not fit below it. How can I place the caption in the adjacent column? See image for clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) (or [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)) to place an ad-hoc float caption in the following way:

```
\captionof{<type>}[<toc entry>]{<caption>}
```

The following minimal example uses the above suggestion, but is heavily dependent on the document layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-3]\lipsum[3]

\captionof{figure}{This is a figure caption}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.99\textheight]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have to consider placing `\captionof` inside a group `{`...`}` to avoid conflicts with other `\label`s.